# react-select not showing assets properly on react-modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-modal

I'm using react-select to have a select field on a modal I create with react-modal. The assets are not showing properly as shown in this image (the arrow is not being shown, and the displayable list is not being properly shown).

[image]

The modal, has a custom z-index (because it is shown on top of another element that has its own z-index) in this way:

```
.Modal {
  // more stuff
  z-index: 81;
}

.Overlay {
  z-index: 81;
}
```

I think this is the problem, but I cannot manage to properly add the z-index to the react select to show ir properly.

I can add the code for the modal and the select if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solved itself. It results that I was not properly including the css for the select. I included it and it started to show just fine.